# Task配列の使い方が知りたい。

Tags: c#

コードここですの部分なのですが。Taskで関数から配列が帰ってきてそれを画面に一つずつ出力したいのですがなぜエラーになるのでしょうか見当がつかないので教えてくれますでしょうか？

```
static async Task<sync_test[]> Thread_class(sync_test[] c,int n,string x)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    await Task.Run(() => 
    {

        for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
        {
            c[i].str = x;
        }

    });


    return c;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "test";
    sync_test[] ss = new sync_test[5] 
    {
        new sync_test(), new sync_test(),
        new sync_test(), new sync_test(),
        new sync_test()
    }; 

    int n = ss.Length;
    Task<sync_test[]> s2 = Thread_class(ss,n,s);


    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        s2[i].str;//ココのコード

        //Console.WriteLine(s2[i].str);
    }


    //sync_test sy = new sync_test();
    //int n = sy.Lengt;

    Task<sync_test[]> t = Thread_class(ss,n,s);
```

Comment: 既にレビュアーによる編集はされていますが、「初心者です」はあなた自身のパーソナルな説明なので、質問のタイトルや本文に含めるのは不適当です。どうしても書きたい場合はプロフィール欄に記載しておきましょう。 / 質問についてもただ「エラーが出ます」だけだと第三者には残念ながら伝わりません。ヘルプの [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) も参照して、より具体的な内容を説明するように見直してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s2`は`Task<sync_test[]>`なので配列のタスククラスです。
タスクに対して直接`s2[i].str`を指定して値を取得することはできません。

なぜならタスクは`<ジェネリック>`クラスの処理状況を監視するクラスとして`Status`や`IsCompleted`などのプロパティが用意されているからです。
タスクには処理結果を取得する`Result`プロパティも用意されているので、ココのコードを下記のように書き換えるとエラーが解消されます。

```
Console.WriteLine(s2.Result[i].str);
```

ところで`Thread_class`というメソッド名は、クラス名と誤解されそうです。
`RunSyncTests`のように動詞から始まる名称を検討された方がよろしいかと存じます。